# how do I remove elements duplicates from Integer array with stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I searched everything about this but I found nothing. So I have an `Integer` array and I would like to remove elements duplicated on it with stream api, for example:

```
Integer[] buffer = new Integer[]{10,23,8,10,8,1,2,1};
```

after  this -> `buffer =  Stream.of(buffer)`...

buffer now has these numbers `{10,23,8,10,1,2}`

So I hope you understand what I mean and I thank you for helping me.

Comment: Did you intend to keep the 10s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Stream API:

```
Integer[] buffer = {10,23,8,10,8,1,2,1};
buffer = Stream.of(buffer).distinct().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to just use a `Set` to remove duplicates:

```
Integer[] buffer = new Integer[]{10,23,8,10,8,1,2,1};
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(buffer));
buffer = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
```